# Hyperlink formula not working despite displaying correct address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDIRECT("'"&C38&"'!A1")))
```

Where C38 contains

```
0999-0165
```

and I have a sheet called 0999-0165.  There are no leading or trailing characters, and since the name in C38 is generated by the sheetname there is no error between 0 and O.

[image]

The sheet has also been saved to my desktop as dtest.xlsx

When I click on the formula, I get the following error:

[image]

MS Help indicates that I should be going down the right path here:

[image]

#### Where did I go wrong

What do I need to do to adjust this formula to make it work so that I can simply copy the formula up or down to create other links for other reference sheetnames in column C?

I also did the work around from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695579/formula-information-displaying-correctly-but-link-information-is-not?rq=1) but it did not seem to help.

### Muddying the water

When I use a direct cell reference and drop the indirect part for testing purposes to make it look the same as the MS Help recommendation, I wind up with the same error:

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",'0999-0165'!A1))
```

And BTW, the above formula winds up displaying the same as the Indirect one.  Complete with adding the $

Comment: You want the name to look like `[dtest.xlsx]'0999-0165'!$A$1`. The single quotes are slightly off.

Comment: Those ' are completely generated by the CELL function.  note my formula only uses A1 but the displayed address has $A$1.  When I remover the ' from the cell reference in the indirect part since there are no spaces in the sheet name, I wind up with #REF! error.

Comment: Yeah I'm still thinking about the best way to do this with a formula. My point being that if you do it manually, that's what the hyperlink address is.

Comment: Gotcha.  I was trying to figure out how to easily get the book name since the filename is a required component of the hyperlink address.  I was trying to avoid hard coding the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a long workaround to this, if you don't want to hard-code the workbook name. Get the entire filename with `CELL("filename",A1)` and then extract just the workbook name and the enclosing brackets using `MID` and `FIND`.

```
=HYPERLINK(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1)),FIND("]", CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1)&"'"&C38&"'!$A$1")
```

[image]

Or slightly more simple:

```
=HYPERLINK(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",INDIRECT("'"&C38&"'!A1")),"'[","["),"]","]'"))
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the formula I was using in the link question...seems so ugly when MS help has a cleaner looking solution...the important thing here...UGLY WORKS!

Comment: I think using `CELL` and `INDIRECT` *with a reference on a different sheet* is the problem. It sucks that the output is just ever so slightly off...

Comment: Indirect is not the issue.  I swapped out indirect with an actually click on the cell in a different sheet reference (Avoids typos) and it made no difference.  See muddying the waters update.   (*&#()&*$# MS Help when their own example is not working!

Comment: The problem MAY be that the sheet name is technically a math operation instead of a pure string...I will have to test that later.

Comment: Take my previous comment back. Microsoft's suggestion works if the sheet name has no spaces in it - e.g. `Sheet1` works but not `Sheet 1`. The sheet name `0999-0165` has the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for saving me the testing.seems like   I am also liking the simple substitute option.  One advantage of the first formula over the second, is that INDIRECT is a volatile function, and the first option completely avoids that issue.  Over a small list not that big a deal.  But if things on a re-calc bog down, it will be one of the items adding to the slow down.